# ktrain, while installing it by using pip command in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-ec2, anaconda, data-science

**pip install ktrain**
while installing ktrian getting below error. please give me any solution.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-led5_fp5\ktrain\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-led5_fp5\ktrain\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-led5_fp5\ktrain\pip-egg-info'
cwd: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-led5_fp5\ktrain
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-led5_fp5\ktrain\setup.py", line 5, in 
readme_file.readline()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1205: character maps to 
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Hi, I think the last line is pointing you in the right direction: `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`. You need to look in the logs. At a glance it looks like it's trying to open an empty file `File "", line 1`. By the way, I see you are running this from the administrator account, which is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the current `README` file for v0.17.x of *ktrain* contains Chinese characters. The default Windows encoding of `cp1252` has trouble with this.  I think this may be resolved in v0.17.3 of ktrain (where `setup.py` opens the README with utf8 explicitly), if you try installing again.

If it still doesn't work, you can change the encoding on Windows to utf-8 as [described here](https://dev.to/methane/python-use-utf-8-mode-on-windows-212i)